# Devise rendering default views from gem instead of generated ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I generated views/controllers for two user models upon installing devise. For whatever reason, the views that are included inside of the gem itself are being rendered instead of the ones that I added.

```
/views/users/registrations/new.html.erb
/views/bizusers/registrations/new.html.erb
```

Current route configuration

```
devise_for :biz_users, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }
  devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }
  devise_for :admins, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }
```

I solved this problem before in a different way, but it was hard to manage due to the separation of concerns that needed to be in place for the users. Can help you fix this issue please?

Answer (score 7):

In the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file, set `config.scoped_views = true` to make devise use the generated views for each devise model instead of the same gem views.