# Render Custom views instead of default Devise views- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rendering

I have changed the views generated by the Devise gem but Rails keeps rendering the file from Devise's gem file path.

Rendered /Users/Jeremy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb

P/S - I've already changed config.scoped_views to true

Comment: similar question asked here, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953848/devise-rendering-default-views-from-gem-instead-of-generated-ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Overriding** the default `Devise’s views` is simple and straight forward, what we need to do is just generate those views in our `app/views` folder by the following single command.

```
rails g devise:views
```

The following `views` are generated.

```
app/views/devise/confirmations
app/views/devise/mailer
app/views/devise/passwords
app/views/devise/registrations
app/views/devise/sessions
app/views/devise/shared
app/views/devise/unlocks
```

No other changes are necessary.
**Or** if you have already done it,you need to move folders inside `app/views/devise`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Haml, then the following terminal invocation is useful as a second step after generating views:

```
$ gem install html2haml

$ for file in app/views/devise/**/*.erb; do html2haml -e $file ${file%erb}haml && rm $file; done
```