# gem Devise don't working render view in folder project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i want to custom view sign_up use deveise
 i use:

```
rails generate devise:views groups/brokers/buyer -v registrations confirmationsbuyer
```

and i custom code in file

```
  app/views/groups/brokers/buyer/registrations/new.html
```

but when i run this, it render to view html file in gem folder

```
Started GET "/buyers/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-24 11:10:00 +0700
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
Rendered /home/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3.2.2/gems/devise-3.5.6/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered /home/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails3.2.2/gems/devise-3.5.6/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.1ms)
```

i want to render to file new.html in app/view..
how to fix this???

Comment: Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953848/devise-rendering-default-views-from-gem-instead-of-generated-ones

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the codes in

`app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

that is the default sign_up page when using **Devise**.

If you plan to use different page, you need to update the **Routes**.

It's a little more work than, changing the file as mentioned above.
Because it has functions in controller as well.